# Could aluminium dust inside a Macbook Air create a short circuit?

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Air and I'm very happy with it, except for the fact that it made a creaky noise. It turned out the bottom plate wasn't screwed on properly and I had to reseat it (I tried to let a Genius do this, but out of the three Geniuses I visited, no one of them had  the proper screwdriver and wanted to take my Macbook for repair or switch it for a new one, I refused this because I don't want to live for a week or more because of such a stupid problem). 
So I bought a special pentalobe screwdriver and screwed the bottom plate off. I noticed there was some aluminium dust inside the Macbook Air because the plate has been moving a little and has been scraping onto the body.

Could this dust create a short circuit theoretically?

One little problem is that one screw (of the 10 screws) doesn't tighten anymore, because the bottom plate has been screwed on wrongly in the first place. What kind of glue is the best to use to attach the screw? Of course it must be possible to unscrew it at some point when I want to install a new/bigger SSD.

This might sound terrible to the Apple fans who don't want to mess with their machines, but I don't think getting it repaired by a Genius or switching it with a new one solves anything, because this creaking problem is very common and it might start all over again.

Comment: Curious what three stores didn't have the tools to open a very common Apple screw. Any genius I've ever talked with would have answered what screw locking product to use, had screw kits on hand to replace yours and remedied a loose bottom case while you waited. Something seems off here...

Comment: I had an Air that wasn't sitting flat myself, which was caused in part by the same problem—a poorly-seated bottom—and the Genius Bar was able to deal with it inside of five minutes.  Your Genius Bars are defective, I think ;)

Answer (score 3):

Loctite make a range of semi-permanent gunks for "gluing" screws in place.  A good hardware shop (on-line or in real life) would help.

There would have to be a lost of dust for it to be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Aluminum [is a conductor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminum_wire), so it is theoretically possible that a trail of aluminum dust *could* create a short circuit, but I've never encountered any reports of this causing problems in a computer.